# Search module via n98-magerun

Tags: install

After `n98-magerun.phar extension:search Mage` in root catalog i see nothing. What else could I do?

Answer (score 2):

The extension:search command is a lightweight wrapper of the mage command line tool delivered with Magento.
It searches for extensions on Magento Connect. If you got no result it's possible that the "mage" file in the root folder is missing.

Comment: No, it's not missing.